# Error React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Estoy construyendo un app con react-native y recibo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo donde me saca ese error:

Este es todo el codigo de mi archivo con error:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

import {
    Container,
    Content,
    Header,
    Title,
    CardItem,
    Left,
    Body,
    Right,
    Text,
    Icon,
    Button,
    Spinner,
    Card,
    Picker,
    View
} from 'native-base';
import { Dimensions,AsyncStorage,ScrollView,FlatList,Image,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {Col, Row, Grid} from "react-native-easy-grid";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const Item = Picker.Item;
import { DATA_USER_KEY, TOKEN_USER_KEY } from './constants';
import { VentanaGrilla } from './datosGrilla';

export default class Settings extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        encabezado: [], //Valor de los datos del encabezado del tablero
        datos: [], //Valor de los datos en JSON que trae el WS para armar las grillas
        filtros: [], //Valor de los filtros en JSON que trae el WS para armar las grillas
        dataIsCargada: 0, //Indica si ya se cargo las grillas
        cmbFiltro: [], //Todos los combos de los filtros que tiene el tablero
        cmbCombinaciones: [], //Todos los códigos agrupados que tiene el tablero
        codGrupoBusqueda: null, //Código agrupado que se enviara al WS 
        codGrilla: 0,
        datosModalGrilla: [],
        visible: false,
        fechaActualiza: '',
        botonCerrar: []

    }

    console.log("este es el error"+this.props.dataAcciones);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getDatosGrillas();
}

//Ordena de forma ascendente los índices de un arreglo, útil para ordenar los filtros y las grillas
ksort(obj) {
    var keys = Object
            .keys(obj)
            .sort(),
        sortedObj = {};

    for (var i in keys) {
        sortedObj[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    }

    return sortedObj;
}

//Cambia el valor de los combobox al momento de seleccionar otra opción
onValueChange(key, value) {
    let cmbFiltroActual = this.state.cmbFiltro; //Carga los filtros que existen acutalmente
    cmbFiltroActual[key] = value; //Reemplaza el valor que se cambio
    this.setState({cmbFiltro: cmbFiltroActual}); //Se actualiza el array
}

//Obtiene el código agrupado de la busqueda, de acuerdo a los filtros seleccionados
getTableroFiltro() {
    let datos = this.state.cmbFiltro; //Carga los filtros seleccionados que existen acutalmente
    var indBusqueda = [];

    for (let clave in datos) { 
        indBusqueda[datos[clave]] = datos[clave]; //Recorre todos los filtros, alimentando el nuevo array
    }

    var txtIndBusqueda = 'ID_'; //Prefijo de odos los códigos agrupados que tiene el tablero
    var j = 0;
    let datosIndBusqueda = this.ksort(indBusqueda); //Ordena el índice de busqueda de manera descendente
    for (let clave in datosIndBusqueda) {
        if (j == 0) {
            txtIndBusqueda = txtIndBusqueda + clave;
        } else {
            txtIndBusqueda = txtIndBusqueda + '_' + clave;
        }
        j++;

    }

    //Estlece cual será el codGrupoBusqueda con el que buscara nuevamente en el WS
    this.state.codGrupoBusqueda=this.state.cmbCombinaciones[txtIndBusqueda];
    this.setState({dataIsCargada: 2});


    //Invoca la función de armar las grillas, para realizar nuevamente la consulta al WS con el codGrupoBusqueda
    this.getDatosGrillas();

}

//Construye las grillas que se mostraran en el RENDER del componente
construirGrillas(encabezado, datos, filtros) {

    let listView = [];
    let combos = [];
    let contenedorGrillasFilas = [];        

    //Establece todos los códigos agrupados que tiene el tablero
    let datosCombinaciones = this.ksort(filtros.combinaciones);
    for (let clave in datosCombinaciones) {
        this.state.cmbCombinaciones[datosCombinaciones[clave]] = clave;
    }

    //Construye los combobox con los filtros obtenidos del WS

    let datosCombos = this.ksort(filtros.combos); //Ordena los índices de los combos de manera ascendente
    let keyCombo = 0;
    for (let clave in datosCombos) { //Recorre los filtros

        //Ordena los valores de los  índices de los combos de manera ascendente
        let valoresCombos = this.ksort(datosCombos[clave].valores);             
        var cmbItems = [];
        let keyItem = 0;

        for (let claveValor in valoresCombos) { //Recorre los valores de cada filtro

            //Si el valor esta definido por defecto y no hay seleccionado aun un valor, se establece este por defecto
            if (valoresCombos[claveValor].ind_defecto == 1 && this.state.cmbFiltro['cmbFiltro_' + clave] == null) {
                this.state.cmbFiltro['cmbFiltro_' + clave] = claveValor; 
            }

            cmbItems.push(<Item label={valoresCombos[claveValor].value} value={claveValor} key={keyItem}/>)
            keyItem ++;
        }
        //Se alimenta la vista que contendrá este filtro

        combos.push(
            <View key={clave+901} style={{borderBottomWidth:1,
            borderColor:'#C7D93D',
            margin:3,marginBottom:12}}> 
                <Text key={clave+'aaaaa'} 
                    style={{
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    margin: 0.2,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color:'#08A689'
                }}>
                    {datosCombos[clave].des_ind_busqueda}</Text>
                <Picker key={keyCombo+'clave1'} 
                    mode='dropdown'
                    selectedValue={this.state.cmbFiltro['cmbFiltro_' + clave]}
                    onValueChange={this
                    .onValueChange
                    .bind(this, 'cmbFiltro_' + clave)}>
                    {cmbItems}</Picker>
            </View>
        )
        keyCombo ++;

    }

    //Se carga el botón de la consulta, para cuando se quiera buscar por un nuevo filtro
    if(this.state.dataIsCargada==2){
        listView.push(
            <View key={keyCombo+930}>{combos}
                <Button key={keyCombo+90}
                    rounded block 
                    title="Consultar"
                    color="#C1C1FC"
                    onPress={this
                    .getTableroFiltro
                    .bind(this)}
                    style={{
                    width: width-80,
                    marginHorizontal:40,
                    borderColor: '#888888',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    backgroundColor: '#08A689'
                }}>
                    <Text key={keyCombo+'combo'}>Consultar</Text>
                </Button><Spinner color="green"/>
                <Text></Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    else{
        listView.push(
            <View key={keyCombo+800}>
                {combos}
                <Button key={keyCombo+700}
                    rounded block 
                    title="Consultar"
                    color="#C1C1FC"
                    onPress={this
                    .getTableroFiltro
                    .bind(this)}
                    style={{
                    width: width-80,
                    marginHorizontal:40,
                    borderColor: '#888888',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    backgroundColor: '#08A689'
                }}>
                    <Text key={keyCombo+100}>Consultar</Text>
                </Button>
            </View>)
    }


    //Construye los datos de las grillas
    let datosGrilla = this.ksort(datos); //Ordena de manera ascendente los valores de la grilla
    let keyGrilla = 0;
    let keyCards = 0;
    let tamanoCampo= 100;
    let tamanoFila= 40;
    var numFilaIconGrilla = 0;
    var contenedorGrillasColum = [];        
    var numeroColumnas = 0;
    var valorJson;
    var valorColumna='';
    var distribucionColumna=0;
    var distribucionFila=0;
    var tamanioH=20;
    var tamanioW=1;
    var widthCell=[];
    var contadorCell=0;
    var widthCell1=0;
    var negrilla='';
    var alineacion='';

    for (let clave in datosGrilla) {  //Recorre cada grilla 
        keyCards++;
        this.state.datosModalGrilla[clave]=[];
        let j = 0;
        let datosFila = this.ksort(datos[clave].valores); //Ordena de manera ascendente los valores de las filas
        var filas = [];
        var combinarCelda = new Array(Object.keys(datos[clave].valores).length);
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(datos[clave].valores).length+2; i++) {   
            combinarCelda[i] = new Array(Object.keys(datos[clave].valores[1]).length+2);
        }
        for (let claveFila in datosFila) { //Recorre cada fila de la grilla
            let datosCampo = this.ksort(datos[clave].valores[claveFila]); //Ordena de manera ascendente los valores de las columnas        

                for (let claveCampo in datosCampo) {     
                    if(datos[clave].valores[claveFila][claveCampo]!=null){
                        valorJson=this._obtenerCampoJson(datos[clave].valores[claveFila][claveCampo]);
                    }               
                    else{
                        valorJson='';
                        datos[clave].valores[claveFila][claveCampo]='';
                    }

                        if(valorJson.valor!=null && valorJson.valor!=''){
                            valorColumna=valorJson.valor;    
                        }
                        else{
                            valorColumna=datos[clave].valores[claveFila][claveCampo];
                        }
                        if(widthCell[claveCampo]==null){
                            widthCell[claveCampo]=0;
                        }
                        if(valorColumna.length*9>widthCell[claveCampo]){
                            widthCell[claveCampo]=valorColumna.length*9;
                        }
                }
        }

        for (let claveFila in datosFila) { //Recorre cada fila de la grilla
            j++;
            let datosCampo = this.ksort(datos[clave].valores[claveFila]); //Ordena de manera ascendente los valores de las columnas
            if (j == 1) { //Si  es el primer registro                    
                var columnas = [];
                for (let claveCampo in datosCampo) { //Recorre cada columna de cada fila de la grilla
                    if(combinarCelda[claveFila][claveCampo]==null){
                        valorJson=this._obtenerCampoJson(datos[clave].valores[claveFila][claveCampo]);
                        tamanioW=1;
                        if(valorJson.valor!=null && valorJson.valor!=''){
                            valorColumna=valorJson.valor;     
                            distribucionColumna=parseInt(valorJson.horizontal)*tamanoCampo;
                            distribucionFila=parseInt(valorJson.vertical)*tamanoFila;                                              
                            for(var z=claveFila;z<parseInt(claveFila)+parseInt(valorJson.vertical);z++){ 
                                    combinarCelda[z][claveCampo]=parseInt(claveFila)+parseInt(valorJson.vertical)-1;                                                             
                            } 
                            for(var z=claveCampo;z<parseInt(claveCampo)+parseInt(valorJson.horizontal);z++){   
                                    tamanioW=valorJson.horizontal;
                                    combinarCelda[claveFila][z]=true;    
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            distribucionColumna=tamanoCampo;
                            distribucionFila=tamanoFila;  
                            valorColumna=datos[clave].valores[claveFila][claveCampo];
                        }    
                        contadorCell = 1; 
                        widthCell1=widthCell[claveCampo]; 
                        while (combinarCelda[claveFila][parseInt(claveCampo)+contadorCell]!=null) {
                            widthCell1 = widthCell1 + widthCell[parseInt(claveCampo)+contadorCell];
                            contadorCell++;

                        }
                        columnas.push(                                
                            <Col collapsable 
                                key={claveCampo+'algo'} style={{                              
                                padding: 2,                                         
                                backgroundColor: '#08A689', 
                                borderColor:'#82BF56',
                                height:tamanioH,
                                width:widthCell1,
                                borderTopWidth: 1,
                                borderBottomWidth: (combinarCelda[claveFila][claveCampo]!==true && combinarCelda[claveFila][claveCampo]!=null) ? 0 : 1,
                                borderLeftWidth: (claveCampo==1) ? 1 : 0,
                                borderRightWidth: (claveCampo==Object.keys(datos[clave].valores[1]).length) ? 2 : 1,                                   
                                }} >
                                <Text
                                    key={claveCampo+'text'}
                                    style={{
                                        textAlign : 'center',
                                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                                        color:'white',
                                        fontSize: 12}}>
                                    {valorColumna}</Text>
                            </Col>
                        )
                    }                                        

                }

            } else { //Si no es el primer registro
                var columnas = [];
                for (let claveCampo in datosCampo) { //Recorre cada columna de cada fila de la grilla
                    if(combinarCelda[claveFila][claveCampo]==null){
                        negrilla='N';
                        alineacion='right';
                        valorJson=this._obtenerCampoJson(datos[clave].valores[claveFila][claveCampo]);                            
                        tamanioW=1;
                        if(valorJson.valor!=null && valorJson.valor!=''){
                            valorColumna=valorJson.valor;                                  

                            if(valorJson.alineacion!=null){
                                if(valorJson.alineacion.toUpperCase()=='D') {
                                    alineacion = 'right';     
                                } 
                                else if(valorJson.alineacion.toUpperCase()=='I') {
                                    alineacion = 'left';     
                                } 
                                else if(valorJson.alineacion.toUpperCase()=='C') {
                                    alineacion = 'center';     
                                }  
                            }   

                            if(valorJson.negrilla!=null){
                                if(negrilla.toUpperCase()=='S') {
                                negrilla = 'S';     
                                }  
                            } 

                            distribucionColumna=parseInt(valorJson.horizontal)*tamanoCampo;
                            distribucionFila=parseInt(valorJson.vertical)*tamanoFila;           
                            for(var z=claveFila;z<parseInt(claveFila)+parseInt(valorJson.vertical);z++){ 
                                    combinarCelda[z][claveCampo]=parseInt(claveFila)+parseInt(valorJson.vertical)-1;                                                        
                            } 
                            for(var z=claveCampo;z<parseInt(claveCampo)+parseInt(valorJson.horizontal);z++){   
                                    tamanioW=valorJson.horizontal;
                                    combinarCelda[claveFila][z]=true;    
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            distribucionColumna=tamanoCampo;
                            distribucionFila=tamanoFila;  
                            valorColumna=datos[clave].valores[claveFila][claveCampo];
                        }
                        contadorCell = 1; 
                        widthCell1=widthCell[claveCampo]; 
                        while (combinarCelda[claveFila][parseInt(claveCampo)+contadorCell]!=null) {
                            widthCell1 = widthCell1 + widthCell[parseInt(claveCampo)+contadorCell];
                            contadorCell++;

                        }
                        columnas.push(
                        <Col collapsable key={claveCampo+'delta'} style={{
                                borderColor:'#82BF56',
                                height:tamanioH, 
                                width:widthCell1,
                                backgroundColor : (negrilla=='S'
                                ||distribucionColumna!=tamanoCampo || distribucionFila!=tamanoFila) ? '#08A689' : 'white',
                                borderBottomWidth: (claveFila==Object.keys(datos[clave].valores).length) ? 2 : 1,
                                borderLeftWidth: (claveCampo==1) ? 1 : 0,
                                borderRightWidth: (claveCampo==Object.keys(datos[clave].valores[1]).length) ? 2 : 1,   
                            padding: 2}} >

                            <Text style={{ 
                                textAlign : alineacion,
                                fontWeight: (negrilla=='S'
                                ||distribucionColumna!=tamanoCampo || distribucionFila!=tamanoFila ) ? 'bold' : 'normal',
                                color : ( negrilla=='S'
                                ||distribucionColumna!=tamanoCampo || distribucionFila!=tamanoFila ) ? 'white' : 'gray',
                                fontSize: 12}}
                                key={claveCampo+'text'}>
                                {valorColumna}</Text>
                        </Col>
                        )
                    } 
                    else if(combinarCelda[claveFila][claveCampo]!==true){
                        tamanioW=1;
                        contadorCell = 1; 
                        widthCell1=widthCell[claveCampo]; 
                        while (combinarCelda[claveFila][parseInt(claveCampo)+contadorCell]!=null) {
                            widthCell1 = widthCell1 + widthCell[parseInt(claveCampo)+contadorCell];
                            contadorCell++;

                        }
                        columnas.push(
                        <Col collapsable key={claveCampo+'delta'} style={{
                                borderColor:'#82BF56',
                                height:tamanioH,
                                width:widthCell1, 
                                backgroundColor : (negrilla=='S'
                                ||distribucionColumna!=tamanoCampo || distribucionFila!=tamanoFila) ? '#08A689' : 'white',
                                borderBottomWidth: (claveFila==combinarCelda[claveFila][claveCampo]) ? 1 : 0,                                 
                                borderLeftWidth: (claveCampo==1) ? 1 : 1,
                                borderRightWidth: (claveCampo==Object.keys(datos[clave].valores[1]).length) ? 2 : 1,   
                            padding: 2}} >

                            <Text key={claveCampo+'text1'}>
                                {' '}</Text>
                        </Col>
                        )
                    } 
                }

            }
            //Carga cada fila
            filas.push(
                <Row collapsable  key={claveFila+'aaaacc'} nowrap style={{
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'stretch',
                    flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    {columnas}
                </Row>
            )
        }

        //Arma la grilla finalmente
        numeroColumnas=parseInt(Object.keys(datos[clave].valores[1]).length)*parseInt(tamanoCampo)+parseInt(35);        
        this.state.datosModalGrilla[clave].push(              
            <CardItem
                header
                key={keyCards+'cadda'}
                style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                width: width-50,
                height: 75, 
                borderWidth: 0.5,                    
                backgroundColor: '#08A689',
                borderColor: '#888888',
                borderRadius: 5                    
            }}>                                   
                <Text style={{color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold',}} key={keyCards+'aaaccvvv'}>{datos[clave].des_grilla}</Text>
            </CardItem>
        )

        this.state.datosModalGrilla[clave].push(
            <ScrollView                 
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            key={keyCards} horizontal >
            <CardItem header key={keyCards+'card'} 
            style={{justifyContent: 'center', height:height-340 ,
            flexDirection:'column',  flexWrap: 'wrap', flex: 1}} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}  >                     
            <ScrollView key={keyCards+900} style={{height:height-330 }}>
                <Grid key={keyCards} style={{marginBottom:80}}>

                    {filas}

                </Grid>       
                </ScrollView>                   
            </CardItem>
            </ScrollView>
        )

        numFilaIconGrilla++;   
            contenedorGrillasColum.push(
                    <Col key={numFilaIconGrilla+900} style={{height: 180,width:180, marginRight:0.5,alignItems:'center'}}>

                        <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>  

                            <Button
                            transparent danger
                            key={keyGrilla}
                            title={datos[clave].des_grilla}
                            style={{width: 140, height: 140,borderWidth:1,flexDirection:'column',borderColor:'gray',
                            borderRadius:5}}
                            onPress={() => this.setState({visible:!this.state.visible, codGrilla: clave})}>                                
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{alignItems:'center'}}
                            onPress={this._onPressButton} onPress={() => this.setState({visible:!this.state.visible, codGrilla: clave,
                            fechaActualiza:datos[clave].fecha_actualiza})}>
                            <Image source={require('./../imagenes/grila.png')} style={{width: 70, height: 70,
                            paddingVertical:2,paddingHorizontal:2}}/>
                            <Text key={keyGrilla} 
                            style={{ borderTopWidth:2,borderColor:'gray',marginTop:4,
                            width:110,
                            fontSize: 9,
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            color:'#08A689',     
                            }}>{datos[clave].des_grilla}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>                                                                                     
                        </Button>

                        </View>

                    </Col>)

        if(numFilaIconGrilla>=2){
            numFilaIconGrilla=0;
            contenedorGrillasFilas.push(
            <Row key={keyGrilla+900} >
                {contenedorGrillasColum}
            </Row>)
            contenedorGrillasColum = [];
        }   

        keyGrilla++;            
    }


    if(numFilaIconGrilla!=0){
        contenedorGrillasFilas.push(
            <Row key={keyGrilla+'grilla'} >
                {contenedorGrillasColum}
            </Row>)
    }
    listView.push(
            <Grid key={keyGrilla+'grilla'} style={{width:width,flexDirection: 'column',marginTop:30,
            alignContent:'center',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                {contenedorGrillasFilas}
            </Grid>
    )

    this.state.botonCerrar=[];
    this.state.botonCerrar.push(   <Button key={'mm'+1} transparent onPress={() => this.setState({visible:!this.state.visible})}>
                <Image source={require('./../imagenes/cerrar.png')} style={{width: 40, height: 40,zIndex:20}}/>
            </Button>  );

    return listView;

}

//Realiza la conexión al WS de manera asincrona
getDatosAsync = async() => {

    //Carga los valores con los que se consultará el WS
    let data = this.props.state.dataAcciones; 
    //let dataServer = JSON.parse(data)
    let codAccion = data.cod_accion_sistema;
    let desServicio = data.des_accion_sistema;
    let ruta_app = data.ruta_app;
    let codGrupoBusqueda = this.state.codGrupoBusqueda;

    //Si las variables principales no estan vacías, realiza la consulta
    if (codAccion !== '' && desServicio !== '') {

        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN_USER_KEY);

        await this
            .props
            .actions
           .fetchPost(ruta_app, {cod_accion_sistema: codAccion, codGrupoBusqueda:codGrupoBusqueda,cache:Math.random() }, token);
        let dataWS = await this.props.state.fetchData;
        console.log(dataWS);
        //if(dataWS.error === ''){
            try {
                // Parsea los datos en JSON que obtiene del WS
                let jsonData = JSON.stringify(dataWS);
                let objData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

                //Carga los datos localmente para ser usado en el componente
                this.setState({dataIsCargada: 1, encabezado: objData[0].encabezado, datos: objData[0].datos, filtros: objData[0].filtros});

            } catch (error) { //Si hubieron errores
                console.log(error)
            }
        //}
    } else { //Si hubieron errores
        let mensaje = '';
        if (codAccion === '') {
            mensaje = 'Error el código acción es inválido.';
        }
        if (desServicio === '') {
            mensaje = mensaje + '\n Error el nombre del servicio es inválido.';
        }
        Toast.show({text: mensaje, position: 'bottom', buttonText: 'Ok'})
    }

}
```

Agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Hola! Por favor completa el [tour] y revisa [ask]. El código en imagenes no sirve de nada, agregalo a la pregunta directamente y también lo mejor sería que agregues un [mcve]

Comment: el error es la linea 557 pero con lo que tiene no te podemos ayudar

Comment: seguir los consejos que te da @KacosPro

Comment: @JOSEWILSONMULATOESCOBAR es que sin la información correcta solo puedo lanzar flechas al aire, hagamos una cosa, identifica la linea del error, y copia la función en la que está y la pones aquí en lugar de todo tu código y continuamos :) y porfa borra los comentarios que ya no son necesarios para que no hagan ruido en la pregunta

Answer (score -2):

Hola aunque la pregunta no esta bien formulada por la cantidad de codigo que esta demas, en la funcion getDatosAsync estas accediendo al valor de this.props.state.dataAcciones, lo cual esta mal, ya que debiese ser this.state.dataAcciones o this.props.dataAcciones. Entiende que la respuesta es en base al supuesto que el error esta en la funcion getDatosAsync.
Saludos